# Trying to get a resultset into C# from a php page - not working

Tags: c#, php, json, dictionary, json.net

I am having a function in C# that downloads a JSON object from a PHP page and it works fine as long as it only contains one record. I am reading the JSON into a Dictionary.

```
using (WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    WebClient n = new WebClient();
    var json = n.DownloadString("http://127.0.0.1/testjson.php");

    Dictionary<string, string> htmlAttributes = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

    int ID = Int32.Parse(htmlAttributes["id"]);
    string Phone = htmlAttributes["phone"];
    string Message = htmlAttributes["message"];
    string UID = htmlAttributes["uid"];

    Console.WriteLine(ID);
    Console.WriteLine(Phone);
    Console.WriteLine(Message);
    Console.WriteLine(UID);
}
```

That works fine as long as I am using a JSON objects as below:

```
{"id":26333,"phone":"+46734231233","message":"Testmeddelande","uid":"A774059B-69CE-40D7-809B-C0A63728F5B9"}
```

But when I want to parse more then one record I am getting errors  - and the error I am getting is:

**Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException**: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'data', line 1, position 9.'

The JSON Object looks like this and I have validated it online:

```
{"data":[{"id":26333,"phone":"+46734231233","message":"Testmeddelande","uid":"A774059B-69CE-40D7-809B-C0A63728F5B9"},{"id":26333,"phone":"+46734231233","message":"Wow, det fungerar","uid":"CA528FCA-CD5D-4220-A646-B556FC060550"}]}
```

I am a new beginner, so the solution is maybe obvious?

Best regards, Joakim

Answer (score 2):

Instead of converting the json object into a dictionary object you can create a concrete class as below,

```
public class DataObject // name it properly
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string uid { get; set; }
}

public class DataList
{
    public List<DataObject> data { get; set; }
}
```

And while de-serializing it,

```
DataList objDataList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataList>(json);
```

And while iterating or retrieving data,

```
foreach(DataObject objData in objDataList.data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(objData.ID);
    Console.WriteLine(objData.Phone);
    Console.WriteLine(objData.Message);
    Console.WriteLine(objData.UID);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Almost there, some errors in the foreach loop. Complained about the objData - so i changed that to another variable name. Then it complains about the Data in the statement.

Comment: I have reupdated with the needed changes here. Can you test it back?

Comment: Now I am getting: DataList.data.get returned null.

Comment: Just noticed why the json data is different for a single record and multiple record? How you are generating json data in that PHP page. If you are having a single record itself you should push it into an array like you are doing for multiple records and return it from there. Can you try it with multiple record.?

Comment: I tried both single and multiple records, with the same error.

Comment: Ok, it seems that the JSON object is the error. Even if I have verified it with several of online JSON parser.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution would be to copy sample JSON that you want to deserialize and utilize *paste special* feature of Visual Studio:

[image]

You will get following generated code:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Datum[] data { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string uid { get; set; }
}
```

Once generated simple use following to deserialize and use further:

```
string json = "{\"data\":[{\"id\":26333,\"phone\":\"+46734231233\",\"message\":\"Testmeddelande\",\"uid\":\"A774059B-69CE-40D7-809B-C0A63728F5B9\"},{\"id\":26333,\"phone\":\"+46734231233\",\"message\":\"Wow, det fungerar\",\"uid\":\"CA528FCA-CD5D-4220-A646-B556FC060550\"}]}";
Rootobject htmlAttributes = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);

int ID = htmlAttributes.data[0].id;
string Phone = htmlAttributes.data[0].phone;
string Message = htmlAttributes.data[0].message;
string UID = htmlAttributes.data[0].uid;
```